# Oracle SQL Subquery to Select Column Names With Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery

I have table `per_person_names_f` with columns `full_name` and `name_type`, I want to make 2 column results, one is `full_name` in english and one for arabic, with that being said, if `name_type` = `GLOBAL` then its english, and if its = `SA` then its arabic,

```
(SELECT full_name "english name" 
FROM per_person_names_f
 WHERE name_type = 'GLOBAL'),
 (SELECT full_name "arabic name" 
FROM per_person_names_f 
WHERE name_type = 'SA')
FROM per_person_names_f
```

I know the syntax is messed up as I'm new to the language, how can I fix the query ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a `CASE WHEN` use case:

```
SELECT 
CASE name_type
 WHEN 'Global' THEN full_name END AS "english name",
CASE name_type
 WHEN 'SA' THEN full_name END AS "arabic name"
FROM per_person_names_f;
```

I don't know what you mean by "solved it with self join", but I recommend do not use `JOIN` if not required because this can cause bad performance.