# Oracle SQL case statement with join gives weird results

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table `per_person_names_f` with columns `full_name` and `name_type`, when `name_type` is equal to `SA`, then `fullname` is Arabic, if `GLOBAL`  then it's English. I want the result to show 2 columns for Arabic and English names.

```
SELECT
    rownum,
    CASE name_type
        WHEN 'Global' THEN full_name 
    END AS "english name",
    CASE name_type
        WHEN 'SA' THEN full_name 
    END AS "arabic name"
FROM 
    per_person_names_f
```

But it ends with weird results, column `english name` is empty and `arabic name` shows some `null` values, what's wrong here knowing that data does certainly exist?

Comment: Your description refers to `GLOBAL` in uppercase, but your code has `'Global'` in mixed case. If the English name column is null for all rows then I imagine that's because you have the wrong case in the code. And if you are expecting the same name shown as  both English and Arabic, then how are the two rows in the table for a given name related?

Comment: yeah its ```GLOBAL```, that's true but still give nulls, not like the result i expected, they are related through ```person_id```

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data and the result you expect for that data.

Comment: You already asked that question, you've got a correct answer from me and instead of accepting that answer, you just ignored that and created a new question. That's very bad behaviour, I will flag that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573227/oracle-sql-subquery-to-select-column-names-with-conditions/74573938#74573938

Comment: Or if Jonas' answer wasn't correct - that is, not *wrong* but didn't solve your real problem, as it presumably didn't since you've copied the query from that answer into this question - then you should have commented on that answer explaining why, and improved that question if it needed more information.

Comment: sry guys, im so pressured these days as Im starting my career, i know im careless about replying to answers, but you really helped me and im thankful

Comment: Jonas, no i didn't ignore your answer at all, it really helped me to learn how ```case``` statement works but not the result i were looking for, i made new post because i don't want to bother you

Answer (score 1):

That's expected, I'd say, because one name excludes another - you can't have BOTH English and Arabic name AT THE SAME TIME, can you? Name is either English, or Arabic.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with per_person_names_f (name_type, full_name) as
  2    (select 'Global', 'my English name' from dual union all
  3     select 'SA'    , 'my Arabic name'  from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select name_type,
  6    case when name_type = 'Global' then full_name end as english_name,
  7    case when name_type = 'SA'     then full_name end as arabic_name
  8  from per_person_names_f;

NAME_T ENGLISH_NAME    ARABIC_NAME
------ --------------- ---------------
Global my English name
SA                     my Arabic name

SQL>
```

From my point of view, that's OK. If you think it is not, what result do you expect?

Comment: Oh well, there's first time for everything in your life. If I guessed it wrong, would you mind, please, posting CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO several sample records, along with desired result? That might help us help you way better.

Comment: Same correct answer with the same correct query to the same question like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573227/oracle-sql-subquery-to-select-column-names-with-conditions Flaged your comment as unkind behaviour. If a correct answer to your question doesn't help you, this means your question has been asked incorrectly or incompletely. Creating a duplicate of the question doesn't make it better.

Comment: @aasemshoshari If you want to get helpful answer for your exact issue, then please: 1) post some sample data (that should be well-prepared to demonstrate the issue representatively, including edge cases); 2) post your current code and an output; 3) post your desired output with a description how you've got it and what is wrong with your current output. Otherwise no one can read your mind and guess your expectations

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH PERSON_NAMES_F(FULL_NAME,NAME_TYPE) AS
(
   SELECT 'ABDUL','SA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'JONNY','GLOBAL' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
 CASE 
    WHEN P.NAME_TYPE='SA' THEN P.FULL_NAME
    ELSE NULL
 END  ARABIC_NAME,
 CASE
  WHEN P.NAME_TYPE='GLOBAL' THEN P.FULL_NAME
 ELSE NULL
END  INTERNATIONAL_NAME
FROM PERSON_NAMES_F P
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description refers to `GLOBAL` in uppercase, but your code has `'Global'` in mixed case. Based on your comment that should be `'GLOBAL'` in the code too.

> but still give nulls, not like the result i expected, they are related through `person_id`

So it seems you do want to get the matching English and Arabic names for the same person, based on the `person_id` value.

You can use conditional aggregation for that:

```
SELECT
    person_id,
    MAX(CASE name_type
        WHEN 'GLOBAL' THEN full_name 
    END) AS "english name",
    MAX(CASE name_type
        WHEN 'SA' THEN full_name 
    END) AS "arabic name"
FROM 
    per_person_names_f
GROUP BY
    person_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aLLuKrI3) with some made-up data.